# invalid_payload while passing variable in slack POST CURL command in gitlab.ci.yml

Tags: gitlab-ci, slack-api

I am keep on getting `invalid_payload` and not able to trigger email to Slack channel.

```yaml
send_email:

  stage:notify

  when:always

  variables:

    PASSED_COUNT: "'{\"passed\":1}'"
    DEPLOY_CURL_COMMAND: 'curl -X POST -H "Content-type:application/json"  --data $PASSED_COUNT https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxx/xxxxxxx/..'
  
  script: 
  
    - echo "Testing Platform"
    - echo $DEPLOY_CURL_COMMAND
    - 'eval "$DEPLOY_CURL_COMMAND"'
    
    - curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json'  --data '{"text":"'$PASSED_COUNT'"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxx/xxxxxxx/..'
```

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68813241/6756090).

Comment: I did try @slauth.                                                                                                                                   $ curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" --data "{\"text\":\"${PASSED_COUNT}\"}" https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXX/XXXX/...../.   did not trigger email nothing happened it is same.

Comment: I made it work.  as you see my variable is already in String so it has to be 'curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" --data "{\"text\":${PASSED_COUNT}}" https://hooks.slack.com/services/...